# Como trabalhar com o protocolo file:// e Angular

Tags: android, angularjs

Queria saber se é possível trabalhar com uma requisição Http:// localmente em minha aplicação e não em um servidor local,se for possível como eu faço isso?
(não precisa necessariamente ser com o protocolo file://).

```
//Cleanup the popover when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.musicActionspopover.remove();
  });

  $scope.openMusicActions = function($event, music) {
    $scope.audioSelected = music;
    $scope.musicActionspopover.show($event);
  };

  $scope.closeMusicActionsPopover = function() {
    $scope.musicActionspopover.hide();
  };

  $scope.playAudio = function($event, audioSelected) {
    // Prevents start the song when it is clicked on the menu
    if ($event.srcElement.tagName == 'I') {
      $event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    var audioSelectedIndex = 0;
    var queueMusics = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.playlist.audios, function (music, index) {
      if (audioSelected.nid == music.nid) {
        audioSelectedIndex = index;
      };

        queueMusics.push({
        id: music.nid, 
        name: music.title, 
        artist: music.interpeters[0], 
        audioUrl: "file://audio/0379442681742547b1cc4baacab409c3/320/ts_.m3u8",//music.audio_url, 
        albumId: music.album.nid, 
        albumCover: music.album.cover, 
        albumBlurCover: music.album.blur_cover, 
        audioType: music.audioType,
        collectionSourceID: $scope.playlist.nid,
        collectionSourceTitle: $scope.playlist.title,
        collectionSourceCategory: "System Playlist"
      });
    });

    $rootScope.$emit("playAudio", {index: audioSelectedIndex, queueName: $scope.playlist.title, audios: queueMusics});
    $scope.closeMusicActionsPopover();
  };
  $scope.playSystemPlaylist = function ($event) {

    playlist = $scope.playlist;
    var audioSelectedIndex = 0;
    var queueMusics = [];

    angular.forEach(playlist.audios, function (music, index) {
      queueMusics.push({
        id: music.nid, 
        name: music.title, 
        artist: music.interpeters[0], 
        audioUrl: music.audio_url, 
        albumId: music.album.nid, 
        albumCover: music.album.cover, 
        albumBlurCover: music.album.blur_cover,
        audioType: music.audioType,
        collectionSourceID: $scope.playlist.nid,
        collectionSourceTitle: $scope.playlist.title,
        collectionSourceCategory: "System Playlist"
      });
    });

    $rootScope.$emit("playAudio", {index: audioSelectedIndex, queueName: playlist.title, audios: queueMusics});
  };

}]);
```

Atualmente estou com esse erro :

> clappr.js:30025 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://audio/0379442681742547b1cc4baacab409c3/320/ts_.m3u8. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>   loadInternal @ clappr.js:30025
>   d @ raven.js:1279

Comment: Bom respondendo a pergunta diretamente, sim porém é interessante que coloque mais informações linguagem e afins para podermos responder de uma forma mais acertiva.

Comment: Tenho uma aplicação em angular, que trabalha com stream hls, existe uma maneira de fazer essas requisições localmente ?

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi a pergunta por isso não vou publicar como resposta... Mas acho que o que você quer é acessar um site local pelo navegador, certo? `http://localhost/` e `http://127.0.0.1/` atendem quase todos os casos (se não atendem é porque o endereço local do seu computador foi reconfigurado).

Comment: Aplicação local ou na Nuvem ?

Comment: @Renan eu estou achando, me corrija se estiver errado, que a aplicação esta na nuvem porém ele quer utilizar algumas requisições locais

Comment: @Otto eu não entendi a pergunta e não sei se é isso. Acho que seu primeiro comentário foi o melhor, essa pergunta pode ser fechada por não ser clara o suficiente se não forem inclusos mais detalhes.

Comment: a aplicação seria nada mais do que um stream de musica parecido com o spotify, dai quero fazer com que ele faça essa requisição das musicas que estão no servidor localmente;

Comment: Sim sim também estou aguardando uma resposta para termos informações plausíveis para poder responder

Comment: Olha ainda não ajudou tanto, mas sim tem como claro, você rodando um servidor http local tipo "xampp" algo assim você terá acesso claro.

Comment: @LucasInacio quando for colocar códigos, faça uma edição na sua pergunte e adicione la

Comment: agora acho que ficou melhor

Comment: Notei que usou a tag android, você então esta usando webView?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é segurança.

> clappr.js:30025 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://audio/0379442681742547b1cc4baacab409c3/320/ts_.m3u8. ****Cross origin requests**** are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. loadInternal @ clappr.js:30025 d @ raven.js:1279

O que ocorreu aqui é que uma página tentou acessar algo fora do domínio dela, sobre um protocolo no qual isso não é possível (os protocolos suportados estão listados na mensagem de erro).

Você deve utilizar um dos protocolos especificados. Além disso, provavelmente terá que configurar a aplicação ou o servidor para permitir requisições não seguras. E terá uma grande margem para falhas de segurança na aplicação.

Talvez seja o caso de repensar a arquitetura da aplicação e como seu conteúdo será servido. Sugiro abrir uma pergunta específica sobre como evitar requisições *Cross origin* em sua aplicação, quando você detém tanto a página que faz a requisição quanto o conteúdo a ser servido na mesma máquina. Assim você poderá fazer o que tem que fazer com menos código, menos configurações, e sua aplicação será mais segura.

Comment: Acredito que tenha perguntado da maneira errada, vou reformular a pergunta para que possam me ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta simples: **Você não pode**.

O protocolo `file://` possui várias restrições impostas pelo browser.

Entretanto nada impede que você crie um serviço web na sua máquina, e ofereça um site local acessível por uma URL similar a `http://localhost`.

Alguns exemplos de implementação de servidor http simples a seguir:

- **Python** - `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`
- **PHP** - `php -S localhost:8080`
- **NodeJS** - `npm install -g http-server`, seguido de `http-server`

Comment: tem outro protocolo ou requisição que possa usar offline, lembrando que quero trabalhar localmente na aplicação e não em um servidor local.